# Concatenate Variables Batch

Tags: batch-file

The following is a simple batch file that should concatenate twi variables, however, when I echo the concatenated variable, only the current directory shows up (i.e the value stored in %~dp0% and not %~dp0% and %pth%

```
cls


if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==AMD64 set arch=x64
(


set pth=sql\ww

set newpath=%~dp0%pth%

echo %newpath%

)

echo.
echo.
echo Done!
echo.
pause
goto :eof
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) because of the brackets:

```
cls
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==AMD64 set arch=x64
(


 set pth=sql\ww

 set newpath=%~dp0!pth!

 echo !newpath!

)

echo.
echo.
echo Done!
echo.
pause
goto :eof
```